# jquery returning 'UNDEFINED' while trying to get the value of textbox (asp.net)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

While I am trying to get the value of textbox with .val(), Its always showing 'undefined'.
Below is the code i am using. Please help me out friends.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtComment" Width="650" />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmitComment" Text="Submit" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[id$=btnSubmitComment]').click(function () {
    var comment = $("#txtComment").val();
    alert(comment);
});
```

Comment: JoeFletch gave you the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One standard way on asp.net is to get the rendered id and use it on javascript as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=btnSubmitComment.ClientID%>').click(function () {
    var comment = $('#<%=txtComment.ClientID%>').val();
    alert(comment);
});
```

(from the moment you go with ID, and not use some other way to select the controls, like the css, the type etc.

Comment: If the `<%=txtComment.ClientID%>` code is in an external JavaScript file, will the `ClientID` automatically get generated by Asp.Net?

Comment: @JoeFletch If you use external javascript then you use other ways to identify your controls - however the ready() usually is in page, and the code you give here is not general at all, but targeted to a page, so the external javascript file here is not the issue.

Answer (score 5):

asp.net pads the element's returned `id`. Looks like you are using it in the click statement. Did you try this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[id$=btnSubmitComment]').click(function () {//you are using the [id$=] selector here.
    var comment = $("input[id$=txtComment]").val();//use it here too
    alert(comment);
});
```

Or you can use `<%= txtComment.ClientID %>`, but I personally have never used it. I believe that you need to tell asp.net to embed JavaScript files into the page, so that the client side `id` gets placed in the proper places. I will look for a link for this potential solution.

Comment: Thank JoeFletch.. Working now..!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

That's normal, when .net renders HTML the texbox's ID become something like ct_001_txtComment.

- You can addd a css class and get the value from the class.
- Or you can change the following option in web.config to make ids static in page element

  `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="Static"`
- Or you can get it from the Client ID like this: <%=txtComment.ClientID%>

Comment: I have never used the `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="Static"` method. Do you have a link for this method for more background on it?

Comment: Making Client ID Mode static, the HTML is cleaner and all ID's are not renamed! However you have to pay attention to not have the same ID twice. Here is a link with more explanation: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40

Comment: +1 from me on sharing that link! Too bad it is only for Asp.Net 4.0. We mainly use Asp.Net 2.0 at work! I'm not sure what the holdup is! Thanks for sharing!